# Determining If A Blank Key Exists

Tags: clojure

### Edit:

My question is how do I filter out what appears to be a blank key in a zipmap?

Although I have a workaround to my problem, knowing how to filter the key would be very helpful.

### End Edit:

This output

```
:   [: [ ]]   ([ ])   3   ,,
```

was produced by

```
(println first-ent, " ", map-ent, " ", val-ent, " ", (count out-csv), " ", out-csv)
```

in this function

```
(defn missing-accts 
    "Prints accounts found in one report but not the other."

    [report-header mapped-data out-file]
    (spit out-file (str "\n\n" report-header "\n\n") :append true)

    (doseq [map-ent mapped-data]
            (let [first-ent (first map-ent)
                  val-ent   (rest  map-ent)
                  out-csv   (if first-ent
                                (str (name (key map-ent)) "," (first (val map-ent)) "," (last (val map-ent)) "\n")
                                nil)]

                (println first-ent, " ", map-ent, " ", val-ent, " ", (count out-csv), " ", out-csv)
                (if (> (count out-csv) 3)                    
                    (spit out-file out-csv :append true)
                    (println "Skipping: ", out-csv)))))
```

The fact that the output with the blank key has a count of 3 allows me to filter does not seem as clean a solution as being able to detect a blank key. Finding and filtering out a blank key is what has me stumped.

Thank You.

Comment: You question is not clear at all, please try to rephrase it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a blank keyword using:

```lisp
(keyword "")
```

You can use this to filter your list and remove all blank keywords:

```lisp
(filter (fn [[key _]] (not= (keyword "") key)) map-ent)
```